# P&ID questions on reports, connection, etc

Tags: electrical-engineering, chemical-engineering, pid-control, process-engineering, instrumentation

Good day to all of you. I got some questions in my mind regarding on P&ID:

1. In electrical, symbol will have their own default reference name for example **"Motor"** will use **"M"** , while for wire they will have **"N"** for **"neutral"**. So in P&ID they will have specific naming for pipe lines and also instrumentation lines. Can i have, this instrumentation lines reference as **"Signal Line 1"** or better stay as **"Software Link"**?

[image]

2. For reports wise, is it necessary to separate between Pipe and Instrumentation Line? For example, Pipe would have Pipe connection report while Signal Line would have Signal Line connection report? How about their BOM report?

3.Do Instrumentation Line should have the same details as Pipe Line ? Is the information suitable and sufficient?

- Name
- Brand
- Model
- Spec
- Service
- Insulation Type
- Insulation Thickness
- Size/Gauge
- Order No
- Supplier
- Remarks
- Length

4. Based on the diagram, how the connection report should be for Signal 01 and pipeline 01?

**For pipeline 01**

"pipeline 01 connected to IND001 via Signal 01 & T003 connected to T004 via pipeline 01?".

**For Signal 01**

"Signal 01 connected to IND001"?

[image]

5. Is this symbol generally used in P&ID as to link to another pipe?

[image]

Comment: Can you not reference other projects/document packages to see how your company handles these questions? Symbology questions are usually addressed on the P&ID lead sheet.

Comment: You have a lot in one question, which means limited response from this site.